# Dart library visibility

Tags: dart

My Dart app has the following structure:

```
myapp/
    pubspec.yaml
    pubspec.lock
    asset/
        ...
    web/
        logging/
            Logger.dart
            LogLevel.dart
        ...other packages
```

Where the 2 shown Dart files are:

`LogLevel.dart`:

```dart
library logging;

class LogLevel {
    static const TRACE = const LogLevel._(0);
    static const INFO = const LogLevel._(1);
    static const ERROR = const LogLevel._(2);

    static get values => [TRACE, INFO, ERROR];

    final int value;

    const LogLevel._(this.value);
}
```

`Logger.dart`:

```dart
library logging;   // <== compiler error!?!

import "package:logging/LogLevel.dart";

class Logger {
    // ...
}
```

I figured since I put the two classes into a `logging` library/package together, that they would be visible to one another. But that's not the case! Instead on the `import` statement I get the following compiler error:

> Target of URI does not exist: 'package:logging/LogLevel.dart'

What's going on here? How should I be packaging/library-ing my types differently so that they'll be visible to one another?

Comment: you have the same library name two times. not sure if this results in an error or "only" a warning, but you probably shouldn't do that either way.

Comment: Thanks @MarioP (+1) - why is this a **bad** thing?!? In Dart, is a library *supposed* to only consist of 1 source file? Doesn't that seem a bit limiting?!

Comment: oh no, a library can consist of multiple files. you can do this with the `part` and `part of` commands: [dart docs](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#libraries-implementing)

Comment: Thanks again @MarioP (+1) - but I'm still not understanding your original comment. You said "*you have the same library name two times...you shouldn't do that...*". But then you say that "*...a library can consist of multiple files...*", which to me sounds like a conflict with your first statement. If 2+ source files can exist inside the same library, then don't they **need** to have the same library name, such as `library logging;`?!?! Why is it wrong to give both files the same `library` declaration? Thanks again!

Comment: Because by using the `library` statement in both files, you are defining two completely separate libraries, which just happen to have the same name. That's not the same thing as defining one library with multiple parts. The parts also only get the `part of` declaration - `library` only goes into the "main" library file, which also is the file intended to use with the `import` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import them through their relative path without referring to the package:

```
import 'LogLevel.dart';
```

If you do want to import them as packages, they need to be under the `lib` folder.

Comment: Thanks @Pixel Elephant (+1) - what's the difference between importing `LogLevel` as a "package" under `lib` or importing `LogLevel` as it exists under `web`? Thanks again!

Comment: Putting it under lib has the effect of making the library publicly available to others to import. If you're not publishing your Dart app though, I don't think there's any practical difference. I find the `package` syntax easier to deal with than specifying relative paths.